# Set selectionModel with QTransposeProxyModel

Tags: qt, transpose, qtableview

I have two views.
The first one uses the 'original' model and the second one uses the transposed model. See the general structure below:

```
  original_Model = new QAbstractTableModel(this); 
  transposed_Model = new QTransposeProxyModel(this); 
  transposed_Model->setSourceModel(original_Model);

  original_View= new QTableView(this);
  original_View->setModel(original_Model);

  transposed_View = new QTableView(this);
  transposed_View ->setModel(transposed_Model);

  m_viewTransposed->setSelectionModel(m_viewOriginal->selectionModel());
```

As far as I know, i need the SAME model in the views, that `m_viewTransposed->setSelectionModel(m_viewOriginal->selectionModel());` would work.
My question now is what is the best approach to sync the two selectionModels betweeen the two views. It cant be that difficult, because I only need to switch the columns and rows.
Do I have to rewrite QItemSelectionModel? (A general hint would be enough)

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Hello @eyllanesc I simplified my question. I hope it is now more clear. (sorry i am not often in forums like this)

Comment: I do not want you to simplify but a code that can copy, paste, compile and be able to check what you indicate. Please read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: I don't understand why my answer was deleted but you can use KLinkItemSelectionModel from the KDE API. It does exactly what you are asking

Comment: @IlBeldus yes that is what i am searching for!. Thanks! Maybe it is a bit of an overload, because I only switch between the views, and it is always only one view visible. But that is a good startingpoint